# How to solve Cannot invoke method afterEvaluate() on null object Flutter android, ios working well

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, project

**I'm running an old flutter project using new flutter version.3.0.2, but when im debugging it shows an error like this. It run on ios**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTwMW.png)

and i tried

> Downgrading flutter version,
> Updating dependancies/Reparing dependancies

**Here is my app/build gradle**

```
 def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}


    def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
    if (flutterRoot == null) {
        throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
    }

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '13'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.irings.elitco"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['G:/AAIRINGSMAINAPPS/GITHUB/Elitco/key.jks'] ? file(keystoreProperties['G:/AAIRINGSMAINAPPS/GITHUB/Elitco/key.jks']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.5.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0"
}
```

**project-level build gradle**

```
  buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and  pubspec.yaml

```
    name: elitco
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.29+30

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  badges: ^1.1.0
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  fluttertoast: 3.1.3

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: 0.1.3
  shared_preferences: 0.5.8
  pin_entry_text_field: 0.1.3
  flutter_plugin_pdf_viewer: 1.0.7
  firebase_core: ^0.4.1+3
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.9
  cloud_firestore: 0.12.10
  firebase_auth: 0.14.0+8
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+12
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.32
  geolocator: 6.1.14
  geocoder: 0.2.1
  curved_navigation_bar: 0.3.4
  carousel_pro: 0.0.13
  carousel_slider: 2.3.1
  pin_input_text_field: 3.1.1
  imagebutton: 0.0.6
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+11
  share: ^0.6.3+1
  solid_bottom_sheet: 0.1.9
  smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1
  connectivity: ^0.4.3+2
  provider: 2.0.1
  bubble: ^1.1.9+1
  intl: 0.16.1
  image_cropper: 1.3.1
  screenshot: 0.1.1
  esys_flutter_share: 1.0.2
  delayed_display: 1.0.3
  circular_check_box: 1.0.4
  cached_network_image: 2.0.0
  flutter_downloader: 1.4.4
  path_provider: 1.6.10
  permission_handler: 5.0.1
  ext_storage: 1.0.3
  numberpicker: 1.1.0
  url_launcher: 5.7.10
  country_code_picker: 1.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^1.3.1
  path: ^1.6.4

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - assets/images/lght.png
    - assets/icons/
    - assets/images/


  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:

  fonts:
    - family: opensans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/OpenSans-SemiBold.ttf


    - family: roboto
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf

    - family: raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
```

Comment: Please checkk this : https://flutteragency.com/how-to-solve-firebase_core_web-not-found-in-flutter/